# List Jquery access

Tags: jquery

I am creating an menu and having problem to access the element to hide the menu. So i would be grateful if you can help me out.

```
<ul id="secondary-nav">
<li class="expandable expanded">
<p style="display: none;">
<ul style="display: block;">
<li class="expandable expanded">
<p>
<a href="http://www.example.com">Link text 1.1</a>
</p>
<ul style="display: block;">
<li>
<li class="current">
<li>
<li>
<li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="expandable">
<li class="expandable">
<li class="expandable">
<li class="expandable">
</ul>
</li>
```

how could i access the ul element that has style tag and to change the style display to "none". As this like an unorder list within an unorder list.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('ul').filter(function() {
    return $(this).css('display') == 'block'; // or this.style.display == 'block'
}).hide();
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/QStkd/513/)**

Comment: @thelinhbui what is the problem? mate.

Comment: thank you very much .... I will give the problem another go, I kinda having idea now if i cant then i will need your help later. Much appriciate ..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("*:block").css("display", "none");
```